# How to pass animation style to component with CSS isolation?

Tags: css, blazor

When you have CSS isolation you can "pass" CSS style to component using `::deep` prefix in CSS. Ok, but how to pass entire animation?

Consider:

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    50% { transform: scale(2.5); }
    100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
::deep .pulse {
    animation-name: pulse;
}
```

So this will pass `pulse` CSS style, but the component would need to know also the definition of the "pulse" keyframes -- and here lies the problem. How to pass it as well?

Example of sub component MyComponent.razor.cs file:

```
[Parameter] public string? CssClass {get;set;}
```

MyComponent.razor file:

```
<span class="@(CssClass)">hello</span>
```

Usage:

```
<MyComponent CssClass="pulse" />
```

Comment: You have used an unusual word "pass" - CSS uses selectors, you don't pass anything. Maybe show some html/razor markup as well with more description of what you are trying to do

Comment: @MisterMagoo, I pass the name and it should be relevant in given context. With CSS isolation I don't know how to refer to keyframes.